# Rails 3 Rspec test database persists

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am having a problem with my test database not wiping the data after each run.  I also have cucumber tests and the database is cleared each time when I run those.

The following spec test only works immediately after a rake db:test:prepare, is there something wrong with my test or the spec_helper.rb that is causing the data to persist?

My spec test is:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "/api/v1/offers", :type => :api do
  Factory(:offer)
  context "index" do
    let(:url) { "/api/v1/offers" }
    it "JSON" do
      get "#{url}.json"
      last_response.status.should eql(200)
      last_response.body.should eql(Offer.all.to_json(:methods => [:merchant_image_url, :remaining_time, :formatted_price]))
      projects = JSON.parse(last_response.body)
      projects.any? { |p| p["offer"]["offer"] == "Offer 1" }.should be_true
    end

    it "XML" do
      get "#{url}.xml"
      last_response.body.should eql(Offer.all.to_xml(:methods => [:merchant_image_url, :remaining_time, :formatted_price]))
      projects = Nokogiri::XML(last_response.body)
      projects.css("offer offer").text.should eql("Offer 1")
    end
  end
end
```

My spec/spec_helper.rb file looks like this:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec


  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
end
```

Cheers,
Gazler.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The factory needs to go in a `before(:each)` block:

```
describe "/api/v1/offers", :type => :api do
  before(:each) do
    Factory(:offer)
  end
  context "index" do
    ... etc ...
```

RSpec will rollback any rows created in the `before(:each)` block after each example is run.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently rspec does not clear objects created by FactoryGirl. A popular approach is to truncate the tables as needed. See [here](http://atevans.com/rspec-db-cleaning-causing-mysqlerror-savepoin) and the thread [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/rspec-users@rubyforge.org/msg06582.html) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Move 'Factory(:offer)' to the spec itself - 'it' block.

Comment: Thanks, that worked  Is there any way to have this created outside the it blocks so that I only need to call Factory(:offer) once?